# How to install a new linux distro and remove the old one?

Tags: linux, multi-boot

I have a laptop dual booting to Windows 7 and Opensuse 11.2. However, I'd like to switch to a different Linux distro (probably Ubuntu, that's what I'm used to)

Is there a way for me to do it without losing the Windows 7 setup/data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ubuntu installer lets you take care of any older installations. It would automatically add windows to grub. Just don't install ubuntu over the windows drive. Manually choose the partition when you install ubuntu.

Note: If you have more than physical disk, make sure you install grub to the same place as it's always been.

Comment: +1 on the note regarding grub. This can seriously bite you in the butt if you get it wrong :)